# How can the meromorphic functions be the rational ones?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I am reading Stein's book on Complex Analysis, and it defines:

> **Definition:** A function $f$ on an open set $\Omega$ is meromorphic if there exists a sequence of points $\{z_0, z_1, z_2, ... \}$ that has no limit point in $\Omega$, and such that
>
> $(i)$ the function $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega - \{z_0, z_1, z_2, ... \}$
>
> $(ii)$ $f$ has poles at the points $\{z_0, z_1, z_2, ... \}$

A bit later, there is this theorem

> **Theorem:** The meromorphic functions in the extended complex plane are the rational ones.

From the definition, it appears that meromorphic functions can have an infinite number of discontinuities. However, I believe rational functions are of the form $\dfrac {p(z)}{q(z)}$ where $p,q$ are polynomials, so they can have a maximum of $\deg q$ number of poles. How can a function with an infinite number of poles be rational?

Comment: The extended complex plane is compact, so there is no infinite sequence with no limit point on it

Comment: @kneidell Ah okay thanks!